# Export two list in CSV file in two different column

Tags: export

I have two lists,

```
list1 = {1, 2, 3}
list2 = {4, 5, 6}
```

I want my CSV file to look like this,

```
1 4
2 5
3 6
```

Note that the two lists are created at different times and need to be saved in the CSV file at different times. So I cannot use `Transpose` and then simply export into the CSV file.

There is a good solution given in https://stackoverflow.com/a/7417916. However, `mydata1` and `mydata2` are in one column and I want the two data sets to be in separate columns.

Comment: Import the existing data from file, add the new column to it in memory, then overwrite the original file with the new data set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As MarcoB suggested,

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]

list1 = {1, 2, 3};
```

Save `list1` in CSV file

```
Export["datafile.csv", list1];
```

When `list2` becomes available

```
list2 = {4, 5, 6};
```

Add `list2` to data file

```
Export["datafile.csv",
  Transpose[{
    Import["datafile.csv"] // Flatten,
    list2}]];
```

Looking at saved data

```
Import["datafile.csv"]

(* {{1, 4}, {2, 5}, {3, 6}} *)
```

Comment: Yeah, this is the solution I was also thinking of. If one wants to add another list to the file, then have to use Export["datafile.csv", MapThread[Append,{Import["datafile.csv"], list3}]]